# How does water at different temperatures behave when they are mixed?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, fluid-dynamics

If I were to inject a constant flow of water at T1 into a reservoir of water at T2, how does that effect the temperature of the mixture at different points in the reservoir?

In other words, what effect will I observe if I were to inject a flow of water tinted with red ink at T2 into a pool of water at T1? Which spots will turn red first?

Comment: As stated I do not think that it is possible to answer this question. I suspect the question will still be difficult when a complete question is given.  For example there would be a significant difference between injection at the top of the reservoir or at the bottom.

Comment: Agreed; the question as-is is too borad and encompasses a lot of fluid dynamics.

Answer (score -2):

The spot that you injected the red ink will turn red first of course.